# Don't match if string contains characters except allowed ones after certain pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match simple (fake) HTTP requests:

`GET /path/to/file HTTP`, 
`GET /path/to/file HTTP/11`, 
`GET /path/to/file HTTP/1.1`

I'm currently using: 

`^GET.+?(?:HTTP)\/?[\d]*\.?[\d]*`

However, this also matches `GET /path/to/file HTTPfoobar`, which I don't want. How do I make this boolean? i.e. match either of the 3 first patterns, but fail for anything else.

Comment: `$` is your friend at the end of the regex there.

Comment: Please specify language you're using in tags

Answer (score 0):

I added the anchor to the end and it works as intended. Also simplified by changing the positive lookahead to a non-capturing group.

It was also pointed out that the pattern would match something like `GET /path/to/file HTTP123` so I added `(?!\d)`.

Final expr I'm using was: `^GET.+?(?:HTTP)(?!\d)\/?[\d]*\.?[\d]*$`

One that strictly matches [...]HTTP/num.num is `^GET.+?(?:HTTP)(?:\/\d+(?:\.\d+))?$`, thanks Matt!

Comment: This regex also matches `GET /path/to/file HTTP1.1`
`GET /path/to/file HTTP/.1`
`GET /path/to/file HTTP/1`

Comment: Try `^GET.+?(?:HTTP)(?:\/\d+(?:\.\d+))?$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AK4tdw/2)

Comment: The first 2 are okay for my purpose. I *did* edit it to `^GET.+?(?:HTTP)(?!\d)\/?[\d]*\.?[\d]*$` so that something like `GET /path/to/file HTTP1` will fail though.

Comment: That should be `(?:/\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` otherwise, `(?:/\d+(?:\.\d+))?` forces it to match `/11.1` but won't match `/11`